# iPhone web dev with jqTouch

Tags: jquery, ios-simulator, iphone, jqtouch

I am some real trouble getting the transitions working for my iPhone site, I am trying to add the 'flip' transition using,

```
<a class="button flip" href="#about">About</a>
```

However I get no flip transition nor do is navigate to the about anchor, here is my HTML,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />  
        <title>Elfm Iphone</title>
        <script src="javascript/jquery.1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="javascript/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqtouch.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/apple/theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

        <script type="javascript/text">
            $.jQTouch({
                icon:'kilo.png',
                statusBar:'black'
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="about">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Some about blurb, telling the users about the station and the site, in most cases this won't be a very extensive page, just some background information, nothing that will overface the user and not want them to carry on listening. I would probably be a good idea to push the user to the stream as well. This could be done as an internal link, something like, why not listen to our <a href="http://www.twovalleysradio.co.uk/iphone/stream.pls">live feed?</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="blog">
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <h1>Blog</h1>
                </div>
            <p>The blog should be an easy things to implement we should just be able to use the stations RSS feed from wordpress and then style up the entries with CSS to match the look and feel of the sites. We could possibly implement the nice listing features that come with the theme available and if not we could easily build our own theme.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="home" class="current">
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <a class="button flip" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                </div>
                    <div id="header">
                        <img src="images/elfm-header.png" alt="ELfm" title="ELfm" />
                    </div>
                        <div id="content">
                            <p>Here's a load of text about is and where it's based and why it's coll and who listen to it and a load more blurb and now I'm just adding filler for the sake of it and I know dynamic text is a pain because then we have to consider what happens if there is too much of it but we'll show a live preview on the web service of what the app would look like.</p>
                        </div>
                            <div id="play">
                                <div id="button">
                                    <a class="play_stream" href="">
                                        Play
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="twitter">
                <div id="tweet">

                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I am testing this is Chrome and Safari and also the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to replace `"javascript/text"` with `"text/javascript"` :)